# How may I know framework behind an iOS Game?

Tags: iphone, ios, game-engine

I would like to know which `framework or development tools,IDE` behind for any `iOS Game`.
I have tried on google but i didn't found any clue. Please help me for knowing framework behind iOS games.

I have listed some games here. Please let me know if any body know development tools,framework,IDE behind listed games.

```
1)Grand Defense.
2)Tower Defense.
3)Castle Defense.
```

There are many games such like listed games. I want to know development tools behind particular iOS Game. I will appreciate for any help.

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to precisely know which game uses what, do the following:

1. Download the game. Decrypt it using some common cracking tools (I do not encourage piracy however!)
2. Run the class-dump utility on it (google it!), this will generate a list of classes the game has inside.
3. Compare the class names to the most common game engines to see exactly which one used in the particular game.

Comment: H2co3: It's good answer and added +1 for that

Answer (score 0):

you say **`Frameworks`** means Opensource and Game Engine??

if right, refer a following site:

http://www.tonylea.com/2011/best-iphone-game-frameworks/

http://maniacdev.com/2009/08/the-open-source-iphone-game-engine-comparison/

In Generally, If you are using objective-C, IDE is xcode. I recommend.

See [GameSalad](http://www.gamesalad.com) without code development Game.

**`Tower Defence using a cocos-2d Tutorial following below:`**

[Tower Defence Tutorial for cocos-2d part1](http://www.iphonegametutorials.com/2011/04/11/cocos2d-game-tutorial-how-to-build-a-tower-defense-game-for-the-iphone-part-1-creep-waves/)

[Tower Defence Tutorial for cocos-2d part2](http://www.iphonegametutorials.com/2011/04/15/cocos2d-game-tutorial-how-to-build-a-tower-defense-game-for-the-iphone-part-2-placing-towers/)

Comment: I already go through above references but i wanted to know game engine behind listed games. Are they developed in cocos2d or any other framework?

Comment: I edited post . please check out about cocos-2d tutorial for tower defence.

Comment: Can you tell me that Grand Defense is made in cocos2d or not?

Comment: I don't know. Please contact the Grand Defense developer directly.